# TextView not appearing on canvas

Tags: android, view, textview, android-canvas

I want to add a textView on a relative layout dynamically, and i want to show it on a canvas. I have tried out the following code. Please help me to find out what's wrong!. Thanks in advance.

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity 
{

```
Paint p= new Paint();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View myView= new Panel(this);

    setContentView(myView);
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);

}


class Panel extends View
{
    RelativeLayout rl= new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);


        tv.setText("Helllllloo");
        rl.addView(tv);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        rl.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawText("helllo canvas!1!!!!!!!", 0, 100, p);

    }



}
```

}

Comment: Hello Canvas is displaying here. But not hellllo..   why this is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding seperate views to relative layout and set contentview as that relative layout!